# Is there a portable way of finding if a path is absolute, using Python?

Tags: python, absolute-path

Is there some built-in function that tells me if a path is absolute or not? I'd like something that is platform independent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`os.path.isabs`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isabs) function does this.